# How to configure resources that work different max hours per day

Tags: ms-project

I have three groups of resources:

Group one - onshore permanent employees that work 7.5 hours max per day
Group two - onshore contact employees that work 8 hours max per day
Group three - offshore contract employees that work 9 hours per day

I've created individual calendars for each group with the work hours allowed per day as follows:

Group one - 8:00 AM to noon and 1:00 PM to 4:30 PM
Group two - 8:00 AM to noon and 1:00 PM to 5:00 PM
Group three - 8:00 AM to noon and 1:00 PM to 6:00 PM

However, I cannot determine how to change the **max hours per day** to differ across the three groups, as this seems to be a global setting for the entire project schedule.

Any advice?

Tx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your comment regarding "**max hours per day**".  Are you referring to the setting in **File > Options, Schedule** - "**Hours per day**" and "**Hours per week**" setting?  Those settings merely translate "days" and "weeks" expressed in the duration field into the correct number of hours.

[image]

Assuming the majority of work is being done by your permanent employees, I'd set "day" to 7.5 and "week" to 37.5.  If you then assign a 2-day task to a 8 hour per day contract employee, they will accomplish the 15 hours of work in less time (finish date/time will adjust.).